# multiple select and delete on gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

when i check the check box it able to loop and get the userid and productname but why not able let me delete?

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            var check = row.FindControl("chkdelete") as CheckBox;
            if (check.Checked)
            {
                string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
                var uid = row.FindControl("lbluserid") as Label;
                var pid = row.FindControl("lblproductname") as Label;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from ProductReview where userID=@id and productid=@pid", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", uid.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", pid.Text);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }

        }
```

Comment: What problem or error are you getting?

Comment: @Mickey you have to rebind the gridview after delete the record.

Answer (score 0):

> can you try the same thing like this.

```
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
 {
            var check = row.FindControl("chkdelete") as CheckBox;
            if (check.Checked)
            {              
                var uid = row.FindControl("lbluserid") as Label;
                var pid = row.FindControl("lblproductname") as Label;

                 DatabaseHelperClass.DoDatabaseOperation(uid.Text.Trim(), pid.Text.Trim());

            }

}


Class DatabaseHelperClass
{
   Public static void DoDatabaseOperation(string uid , string pid)
    { string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from ProductReview where userID=@id and productid=@pid", con);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", uid);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", pid);
      con.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      con.Close();

    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is same as the Mickey's question.same code but you use Class instead of the delete code.

Comment: what I am saying that your not going to give her solution instead of you are write code with taking Class.Are you sure by this way problem get solved?